# Dynamically change view inside view in Android

Tags: android, view, dynamic

I have this RelativeView with 3 radiobuttons on top. I want to change the bottom part of the view when the user clicks on one of the buttons.

The blue part is the place i want to load different Views in.
[image]

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    if (checkedId == iVerzekeringen){
        layout.removeView(body);   // THIS PART IS
        layout.addView(testview);  // NOT WORKING
    }
    else if (checkedId == iPersoonlijk){
    }
    else if (checkedId == iNotities){
    }
}
```

How can i load different Views into the blue part?

Comment: Have you consider using the TabWidget for the same task?

Comment: Yes I did, but I have a save button (opslaan) which saves information off all 3 views. And it looks really 'ugly' with a large Save button on top or on bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I kinda found the answer:

```
layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rellayout);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
layout.addView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gegevens_verzekeringen, group, false), 1 );
```

This loads the view over the parent xml. I want it to load it over just the 'body' part (the blue part in the picture)

I declared the body like this:

```
body = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.body);
```

But when i do `body.addView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gegevens_verzekeringen, group, false), 1);`

It sais `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 count=0`

How can i fix this?

Edit: Got it:

```
body.addView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gegevens_verzekeringen, null));
```

Answer (score 0):

- use `findViewById` to get a reference to each `RadioButton`
- Register an `OnClickListener` using `setOnClickListener` on each `RadioButton`
- Inside your `OnClickListener` callback, load a different background

Comment: I already have a method to determine which radiobutton is chosen. The only problem is that I can't set a different xml-view inside the current view. I've edited my question for my method