# Calling Button from different view in Android

Tags: java, android, view, android-activity

In my app I have 3 radiobuttons on top of the view. When i choose one the 'body' underneath that changes to the XML-view i defined.

(If you want more information + pics, I asked a question about this earlier: [Dynamically change view inside view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427278/dynamically-change-view-inside-view-in-android))

Now i want to call and change the text of the buttons and edittext's from the different views.

When I do `btnAutopech = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAutopech);` it's gives an NullPointerException.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.......

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout ll= new LinearLayout(context);
ll=(LinearLayout)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gegevens_verzekeringen, ll);
btnAutopech = (Button) ll.findViewById(R.id.btnAutopech);
```

Thanks.........

Comment: Thanks this worked!! Had to add body.addView(ll); though.. :D

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you solved the last question you linked to. If your inflating new views into the area you want to change then you won't be able to retreive a reference to them using finViewById. I.e. they don't actually exist.

When you re-display your view, within which you want to display text based, on your other views outcome, you would have to re-assign the text when you re-attach/display your view. You could then assign text from a member variable of the class, or perhaps from sharedPreferences or a contentProvider.

EIther way, this sort of all depends on how you've solved the issue of your original question and when you attach/remove your views.

To summerise:

It looks like your removing your other views when you visit other views, so store your data in a member variable that persists.

- attach view A
- got to view B
- Click button or something in view B and update member variable used by view A
- Go to view A (Removing view B and attaching view A)
- set text on view A from member variable (updated as a result of clicking button in view B for example)

Comment: So what you say is that in stead of loading the 3 views from an XML-view i should create the buttons code-wise and hiding/showing them when switching views?

I could do this but then I would've wasted 1,5 week.. Are you sure there is no other way around?

Comment: Actually, I can't do this. I need a solution for the current external XML-view I already have :( ...