# How can I set conents of View1 to View2?

Tags: java, android, android-view

```
Private View View2;
...
View View1 = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, dataset, renderer);
...
View2 = (View)findViewById(R.id.View2);
...
```

1. The View1 shows a Line Chart generated from a dataset.
2. The View2 is a View of the MainActivity.
3. View1 can show with `setContentView(View1);`.
4. How can I show the Line Chart in View2?

Comment: conents? what does that means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to SWITCH contents between Views, refer to the ViewSwitcher.
example as: [Dynamically change view inside view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427278/dynamically-change-view-inside-view-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you probably need to replace these views, If I'm correct, you can try this codes

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) View1.getParent();
int index = parent.indexOfChild(View1);
parent.removeView(View1);
parent.addView(View2, index);
```